An error occurs when sending a message containing Japanese to Discord from Raspberry Pi Pico W (MicroPython)
I made micropython code to send Discord DM with Raspberry Pi Pico W.
Not use library(ex. Discord.py), directly connect Discord REST API.
import urequests, ujson

#Omit Wi-Fi connection

DataObj = {
"content": "Hello, World"
}

Header = {
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"authorization": "Bot \<token\>"
}

Req = urequests.post("https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/\<channel.id\>/messages", data=ujson.dumps(DataObj), headers=Header)
print(Req.status) # 200 OK
Req.close()


This code is OK, but when content contain Japanese characters (correctly multibyte characters), An error "The request body contains invalid JSON" occured. so I cannot send Japanese DM.
import urequests, ujson

#Omit Wi-Fi connection

DataObj = {
"content": "こんにちは、世界" # same meaning Hello, Wolrd"
}

Header = {
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"authorization": "Bot \<token\>"
}

Req = urequests.post("https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/<channel.id>/messages", data=ujson.dumps(DataObj), headers=Header)
print(Req.text) # {"message": "The request body contains invalid JSON.", "code": 50109}
Req.close()


I carried out next steps.

data="{'content':'こんにちは、世界'}" Directly write JSON
data="{'content':'\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f\u3001\u4e16\u754c'}" Use Unicode escape
Use URL encode (Could send messages but message wasn't convert Japanese characters)
Run on VSCode

All try is not solved this problem.

Windows11 Pro 23H2
Thonny 4.1.4 (Python 3.10.11)
Raspberry Pi Pico W (RPI_PICO_W-20240602-v1.23.0.uf2)


Some things to try: send the request to your own HTTP server so you can look at it and see exactly what headers MicroPython is sending (could it be sending the wrong Content-Type?)  And to rule out a problem with the Discord API, see if you can send the same request to Discord using different tools, like Python or curl on a PC.
